# Windows Phone 8 - Saving Microphone File as .wav

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using following method to save a recording of microphone in WP8 to a file:

```
        private void SaveToIsolatedStorage()
    {
        // first, we grab the current apps isolated storage handle
        IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        // we give our file a filename
        string strSaveName = "myFile.wav";

        // if that file exists... 
        if (isf.FileExists(strSaveName))
        {
            // then delete it
            isf.DeleteFile(strSaveName);
        }

        // now we set up an isolated storage stream to point to store our data
        IsolatedStorageFileStream isfStream =
                 new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strSaveName,
                 FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());

        isfStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);

        // ok, done with isolated storage... so close it
        isfStream.Close();
    }
```

The file is saved. However, I do not know where does it save it, and how can I access it.
I wish to permanently save it to the device so I can access it from outside the app (Let's say from a file explorer app, or from the music player app).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get saved file name from isolated storage and use this to read this file from stored loacation:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
String[] filenames=myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames();
```